# Struggling with array of markers for Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I started to list my markers individually for my Google Map, but quickly realised this was 
inefficient. I have tried to create an array to put the markers onto my map, but it is not showing anything, can you see where I have gone wrong?

```
function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.474, -1.868);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var image = 'i/hotel-map-pin.png';

        var hotels = [
            ['ibis Birmingham Airport', 52.452656, -1.730548, 4],
            ['ETAP Birmingham Airport', 52.452527, -1.731644, 3],
            ['ibis Birmingham City Centre', 52.475162, -1.897208, 2]
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: hotels[1],
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: hotels[0],
                zIndex: hotels[2]
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your loop you are accessing the hotels array at fixed indexes (1, 0 & 2) rather than the array elements at index i:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
        var hotel = hotels [i]
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng (hotel[1], hotel[2]),
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: hotel[0],
            zIndex: hotel[3]
        });
    }
```

[Here](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo33) is a working example with the fix.

Comment: @Gogster No problems. It was an easy mistake to make.

Comment: why didn't you use a foreach(hotels as hotel) to make your life easier?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/xmwVY/)

First of all you are not accessing your hotels array correctly.  It should be `hotels[i][0]` for title `hotels[i][1]` and `hotels[i][2]` for lat and lng and `hotels[i][3]` for z-index.  Secondly, position takes the `google.maps.LatLng` object with lat and lng as the param.

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.474, -1.868);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var image = 'i/hotel-map-pin.png';

    var hotels = [
        ['ibis Birmingham Airport', 52.452656, -1.730548, 4],
        ['ETAP Birmingham Airport', 52.452527, -1.731644, 3],
        ['ibis Birmingham City Centre', 52.475162, -1.897208, 2]
        ];

     for (var i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(hotels[i][1], hotels[i][2]),
             map: map,
           //  icon: image,
             title: hotels[i][0],
             zIndex: hotels[i][3]
         });
     }
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

Comment: i commented out icon for jsfiddle purpose

Comment: @Kyj112 +1 You beat me to the draw by about 30 seconds with the same answer ;)

Comment: @RedBlueThing oh hehe +1 for you thanks Guru. You are indeed, seniority, on google maps subjects /bow