# Assigning a value from an array to a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

Pretty new at this... I'm trying to generate a dynamic list of markers on a Google Map using data from an array (which will later be populated dynamically from post information on a Wordpress site).

Further below is a simplified version of the code using static data. The problem I am having is that I can't seem to be able to assign the "icon" key with the fifth value from the array (i.e. pinImageX).

The follwing works fine...but obviously displays all markers with the one pin style

```
icon: pinImage1,
```

But using the follwoing doesn't work

```
icon: locations[i][4],
```

I feel I'm missing some syntax to correctly assign the key the value from the array :(

```
var locations = [
['Marker1', -50, 100, 1, 'pinImage1'],
['Marker2', -51, 101, 2, 'pinImage2'],
['Marker3', -52, 102, 3, 'pinImage3'],
];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-50, 100),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
        var pinColor1 = "FF0000";
        var pinColor2 = "00FF00";
        var pinColor3 = "0000FF";

            var pinImage1 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor1,
            new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

            var pinImage2 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor2,
            new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

            var pinImage3 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor3,
            new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        icon: locations[i][4],
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
```

Comment: this may helps u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819379/struggling-with-array-of-markers-for-google-maps-api

Answer (score 1):

`icon` does not take a string, but a direct reference to a `google.maps.MarkerImage` object. What you will have to do is to store all your icon `MarkerImage` objects in an associative array or object (whichever suits your fancy. Object might be handy for the sweet sweet prototype functions), and return from there.

Here is how I got around this on a site for my former employer:

```
        if (markerInfo.icon == undefined || markerInfo.icon == "") {
            for(var i=0; i<this.options.categories.length;i++) {
                if (this.options.categories[i].id == markerInfo.category) {
                    markerURLpic = this.options.categories[i].icon;
                }
            }
        }
```

This was part of the marker-generating function. Essentially, it allowed the users to casually submit a string and have the rest do the look-up. All `MarkerImage` objects are stored in `this.options.categories`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: (Source code fully visible on www.the-vineyard.co.uk/contact.asp if you'd like a proof-of-concept example)

Comment: Thanks Sébastien, your proof-of-concept looks great! Unfortunately your solution is beyond the scope of my javascripting ability.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EqJMM/ should give you an idea of two things: how to do what you want to do, how to lighten up your code. I've wrapped all the functions (assign marker images, assign markers) neatly into an object to lighten the repetitions on the code.

Comment: Awesome! Just one thing though, the infowindow.setContent doesn't seem to be working (i.e. no info balloon pops up on click)

Comment: Thanks Sébastien! Your code is very eloquent and streamlined. It now all works fine in the jsfiddle demo, and also when I copy and paste it into a local html file. However when I add the code to my Wordpress template all I get is a blank map :/ Very frustrating indeed. I may have to use Jack's method for now which works with my current (albiet messy) code and revisit yours later to see if there's anything in my template that is clashing with your solution.

Comment: Can you give me the wordpress URL? I'll see if I can find what is going wrong.

Comment: http://www.ordonline.com.au/map-test/ Code is between <!-- START: Display map --> and <!-- END: Display map -->

Comment: Simple answer: jQuery returns a 404. Make sure that it is on the right path.

Comment: I've replaced the src URL to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js but that still doesn't help. The maps works fine on the local file (which doesn't have the correct URL) so not sure if that's actually the issue.

Comment: Loading the page now throws two JS errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:18
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function `. The first one is because oldIE testing is disabled in jQ1.9 (so use 1.8). Second one is a consequence of the first, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of variable variables doesn't work very well without a scope, so what you would need to do is create an object containing your pin images that will serve as the scope:

```
var pinImages = {
    pinImage1:
        new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor1,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34)),

    pinImage2:
        new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor2,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34)),

    pinImage3:
        new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor3,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34))
};
```

And then you can reference the images like this:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    icon: pinImages[locations[i][4]],
    map: map
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, what you propose seems to make sense, but unforunately I can't get it to work. It seems to ignore the assigned icon value and plot the default marker image even though I've set the value in the locations data set to 'pinImage1' (see: http://www.ordonline.com.au/)

Comment: @NoobCoder Well, you should do `console.log(pinImages[locations[i][4]]);` and make sure the value is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately adding console.log didn't help. Many thanks for taking the time to try help anyways.

Comment: @Noob how did it not help? What was shown on the JavaScript console?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't realise you meant to use the console...I'm a bit new to this. Using your advice I noticed the value stopped after the pin colour was appended to the URL. By removing the pinColor1 variable and placing the colour value in the URL it works fine now (e.g. new google.maps.MarkerImage("...chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FF0000",). Thanks again.

Comment: @NoobCoder Cool! Don't forget to read the [about] section on how to accept answers :)